# socket.io emit to C# using Newtonsoft.json and socketIOClient

Tags: c#, node.js, type-conversion, socket.io, json

nodeJS:

```
io.sockets.on("connection",function(client)
{
  client.emit('Value',{Data:'a string'});
});
```

C#:

```
socket.On("Value", (data) =>
{
  PlainString PS = data.Json.GetFirstArgAs<PlainString>();
  MessageBox.Show(PS.Data);
});
```

C# PlainString Class:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
class PlainString
{
   [JsonProperty]
   public string Data { get; set; }
   public PlainString(){}
   public string ToJsonString()
   {
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
   }
   public static PlainString Deserialize(string jsonString)
   {
      return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlainString>(jsonString);
   }
}
```

error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'PlainString'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

on JsonEncodedEventMessage.cs:39

```
    public T GetFirstArgAs<T>()
        {
            try
            {
                var firstArg = this.Args.FirstOrDefault();
                if (firstArg != null)
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(firstArg.ToString());//line 39
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return default(T);
        }
```

`firstArg = '{ "Data": "connected" }'  (dynamic)`
and
`T =  PlainString`

using: [SocketIO4Net](http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/)
everything looks right, but i always get that error, am i missing something?

Comment: What is the return type of the method containing "return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>..."? This return type is not T, which is causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that library but usually Deserializers return object.

Try this:

```
public static PlainString Deserialize(string jsonString)
{
    return (PlainString)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlainString>(jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, it looks like you just need to set your PlainString class as public.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class PlainString
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public PlainString() { }

    public string ToJsonString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
    public static PlainString Deserialize(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlainString>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

There is a very sim. sample in TestSocketIOClient.cs at line 55 - where I show getting the data as a Part object as well.

```
// cast message as Part - use type cast helper
Part part = data.Json.GetFirstArgAs<Part>();
Console.WriteLine(" Part Level:   {0}\r\n", part.Level);
```

Jim